# DashDB Local Docker Deployment

Tags: docker, dashdb

I have been able to deploy DashDB local (SMP) locally on my mac (using Kite) 3-4 months ago, but recently I am not able to successfully deploy either SMP or MPP using MacOS (Kite) or Linux (on AWS using individual instances with docker running - not swarm).

Linux flavor (Default Amazon Linux AMI)

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-171 ~]$ cat /etc/*-release
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2016.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2016.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2016.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2016.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.03
```

Linux Kernel

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-171 ~]$ sudo uname -r
4.4.11-23.53.amzn1.x86_64
```

Docker Version

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-171 ~]$ docker --version
Docker version 1.11.2, build b9f10c9/1.11.2
```

hostname

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-171 ~]$ hostname
ip-10-0-0-171
```

dnsdomainname

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-171 ~]$ dnsdomainname
ec2.internal
```

In every variant approach I always end up with something like the message below after running:

```
docker run -d -it --privileged=true --net=host --name=dashDB -v /mnt/clusterfs:/mnt/bludata0 -v /mnt/clusterfs:/mnt/blumeta0 ibmdashdb/preview:latest
```

(for SMP) or `docker exec -it dashDB start` (after the run command for MPP).  I tried using the getlogs, but couldn't find anything interesting.  Any ideas?  For SMP I am using a created directory on single host, for MPP I am using AWS' EFS for a shared NFS mount.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-171 ~]$ docker logs --follow dashDB
/mnt/bludata0/nodes cannot be found. We will continue with a  single-node deployment.
Checking if dashDB initialize has been done previously ...
dashDB stack is NOT initialized yet.


#####################################################################
Running dashDB prerequisite checks on node: ip-10-0-0-171
#####################################################################

#####################################################################
Prerequisite check -- Minimum Memory requirement
#####################################################################
* Memory check: PASS

#####################################################################
 Prerequisite check -- Minimum data volume free-space requirement
#####################################################################
* Free space in data volume check: PASS

#####################################################################
 Prerequisite check -- Minimum number of CPU/CPU core requirement
#####################################################################
* CPU check: PASS

#####################################################################
 Prerequisite check -- Data Volume device DIO requirement
#####################################################################
* DIO check: PASS

#####################################################################
 Prerequisite check -- Data Volume device I/O stats
#####################################################################
Testing WRITE I/O performance of the data volume device
32768+0 records in
32768+0 records out
134217728 bytes (134 MB) copied, 33.7435 s, 4.0 MB/s

real    0m33.746s
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m12.040s

Testing READ I/O performance of the data volume device
32768+0 records in
32768+0 records out
134217728 bytes (134 MB) copied, 10.8286 s, 12.4 MB/s

real    0m10.831s
user    0m0.116s
sys 0m0.344s

######################################################################

*************************************************
 Prerequisite check summary for Node: ip-10-0-0-171
*************************************************

* Memory check: PASS
* Free space in data volume check: PASS
* CPU check: PASS
* DIO check: PASS

*********************************************
 I/O perf test summary for Node: ip-10-0-0-171
*********************************************
* Read throughput:  12.4 MB/s
* Write throughput:  4.0 MB/s

######################################################################
Creating dashDB directories and dashDB instance
Starting few of the key services ...
Generating /etc/rndc.key:                                  [  OK  ]
Starting named:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting saslauthd:                                        [  OK  ]
Starting sendmail:                                         [  OK  ]
Starting sm-client:                                        [  OK  ]
Setting dsserver Config
Setting openldap
Starting slapd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting sssd:                                             [  OK  ]
Starting system logger:                                    [  OK  ]
Starting nscd:                                             [  OK  ]
Update dsserver with ldap info
dashDB set configuration
Setting database configuration
database SSL configuration
-bludb_ssl_keystore_password
-bludb_ssl_certificate_label
UPDATED: /opt/ibm/dsserver/Config/dswebserver.properties
set dashDB Encryption
Setting up keystore
dashDB failed to stop on ip-10-0-0-171 because database services didn't stop.
Retry the operation. If the same failure occurs, contact IBM Service.
If a command prompt is not visible on your screen, you need to detach from the container by typing Ctrl-C.
```

Stop/Start

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-171 ~]$ docker exec -it dashDB stop
Attempt to shutdown services on node ip-10-0-0-171 ...

dsserver_home: /opt/ibm/dsserver
port: -1
https.port: 8443
status.port: 11082
SERVER STATUS: INACTIVE
httpd: no process killed
Instance is already in stopped state due to which database consistency can't be checked
###############################################################################
                Successfully stopped dashDB
###############################################################################
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-171 ~]$ docker stop dashDB
dashDB
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-171 ~]$ docker start dashDB
dashDB
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-171 ~]$ docker logs --follow dashDB
```

Follow the logs again

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-171 ~]$ docker logs --follow dashDB
....SAME INFO FROM BEFORE...
/mnt/bludata0/nodes cannot be found. We will continue with a single-node deployment.
Checking if dashDB initialize has been done previously ...
dashDB stack is NOT initialized yet.


#####################################################################
 Running dashDB prerequisite checks on node: ip-10-0-0-171
#####################################################################

#####################################################################
 Prerequisite check -- Minimum Memory requirement
#####################################################################
* Memory check: PASS

#####################################################################
 Prerequisite check -- Minimum data volume free-space requirement
#####################################################################
* Free space in data volume check: PASS

#####################################################################
 Prerequisite check -- Minimum number of CPU/CPU core requirement
#####################################################################
* CPU check: PASS

#####################################################################
 Prerequisite check -- Data Volume device DIO requirement
#####################################################################
* DIO check: PASS

#####################################################################
 Prerequisite check -- Data Volume device I/O stats
#####################################################################
Testing WRITE I/O performance of the data volume device
32768+0 records in
32768+0 records out
134217728 bytes (134 MB) copied, 34.5297 s, 3.9 MB/s

real    0m34.532s
user    0m0.020s
sys 0m11.988s

Testing READ I/O performance of the data volume device
32768+0 records in
32768+0 records out
134217728 bytes (134 MB) copied, 10.8309 s, 12.4 MB/s

real    0m10.833s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.432s

######################################################################

*************************************************
 Prerequisite check summary for Node: ip-10-0-0-171
*************************************************

* Memory check: PASS
* Free space in data volume check: PASS
* CPU check: PASS
* DIO check: PASS

*********************************************
 I/O perf test summary for Node: ip-10-0-0-171
*********************************************
* Read throughput:  12.4 MB/s
* Write throughput:  3.9 MB/s

######################################################################
Creating dashDB directories and dashDB instance
mv: cannot stat `/tmp/bashrc_db2inst1': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `/tmp/bash_profile_db2inst1': No such file or directory
Starting few of the key services ...
Starting named:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting saslauthd:                                        [  OK  ]
Starting sendmail:                                         [  OK  ]
Setting dsserver Config
mv: cannot stat `/tmp/dswebserver.properties': No such file or directory
Setting openldap
/bin/sh: /tmp/ldap-directories.sh: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `/tmp/cn=config.ldif': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `/tmp/olcDatabase0bdb.ldif': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `/tmp/slapd-sha2.so': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `/tmp/cn=module0.ldif': No such file or directory
ln: creating hard link `/var/run/slapd.pid': File exists   [  OK  ]

Starting sssd:                                             [  OK  ]
Starting system logger:                                    [  OK  ]
Starting nscd:                                             [  OK  ]
Update dsserver with ldap info
dashDB set configuration
Setting database configuration
database SSL configuration
-bludb_ssl_keystore_password
-bludb_ssl_certificate_label
UPDATED: /opt/ibm/dsserver/Config/dswebserver.properties
set dashDB Encryption
dashDB failed to stop on ip-10-0-0-171 because database services didn't stop.
Retry the operation. If the same failure occurs, contact IBM Service.
If a command prompt is not visible on your screen, you need to detach from the container by typing Ctrl-C.
```

Comment: For the sake of testing, can you run without docker, to see if it is something about permissions? In other words, is dashDB going wrong, or is Docker going wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, DashDB local is only available as a docker container so I can only test via docker.

Comment: after digging in it appears the db2blu licenses are expired within the ibmdashdb/preview:latest docker build.  Is there a newer repo that should be used with updated license keys?  All of the videos reference this repo.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for testing dashDB Local. 
MPP is only supported on Linux. 
SMP on Mac is only supported using Kitematic with Docker Toolbox v1.11.1b and using the 'v1.0.0-kitematic' tag image, not 'latest'.

To help you further I'd like to focus on a single environment and for simplicity let's start with SMP on Linux and we can later discuss MPP.

Check the minimum requirements for an SMP installation:

- Processor 2.0 GHz core
- Memory 8 GB RAM
- Storage 20 GB

What is the Linux flavor you use? Check with:

```
cat /etc/*-release
```

Make sure you have at least a Linux kernel 3.10. You can check with:

```
$ uname -r
3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
```

Then let's find out what version of docker is installed with:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.12.1, build 23cf638
```

Additionally you need to configure a hostname and domain name. You can verify that you have these with:

```
$ hostname
```

and

```
$ dnsdomainname
```

Also ensure all the required ports are open, the list is long. Check our [documentation](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/admin/local_prereqs.html).

Is this system virtual or physical?

Can you show the entire output of as well as all above checks:

```
$ docker logs -–follow dashDB
```

Try the following steps which if all else is correct may help resolve this issue. Once you see the error:

```
$ docker exec -it dashDB stop
$ docker stop dashDB
$ docker start dashDB
```

Comment: The public preview is no longer available. Please sign up for the dashDB Local Trial [here](http://www.ibm.com/analytics/us/en/technology/cloud-data-services/dashdb-local/). Let me know if you have further questions?